# Is there a part of Stack Exchange for asking about finding c# statistical algorithms

Tags: discussion, algorithm, statistics

I am trying to find an algorithm for Granger Causality in c#. Is this sort of question dealt with anywhere on Stack Exchange?

Or is there some other forum I should look at for questions that are not exactly code problems?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could still post that kind of question on stackoverflow.com.

There are some related forums though..

https://math.stackexchange.com/

https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Good to know - had a similar question to this just closed out last time. I will check out those sites thank you.

Comment: I think the people on Math and Stats will kill you painfully if you ask them for C# code...you can ask them for the the algorithm, though, and then translate it into C# yourself. Also it may be noted that the people at Stack Overflow will most likely also hurt you if ask them to `translate this mathematical algorithm/formula into C# for me`. Of course, you can always go there if you're stuck while doing so.

Comment: Do you think people on Math and Stats would NOT be keen to share - why? I am specifically trying to save myself the effort of re-inventing(or rather writing) the wheel.

Comment: @ManInMoon, maths and stats should be used for determining the algorithm - not an implementation. You can then have go at writing the code then post on stackoverflow for help if/when you get stuck. Or you could post on SO asking about an implementation of the algorithm (not asking if this is the right place to ask about it)

Comment: musefan - I did try asking for implementation on SO - and got my question closed. THAT is the reason I asked about where the right place is!!

Comment: @ManInMoon, well most people are unwilling to do the work for you - as would I be. YOu shoudl really give it a go yourself (if you cannot find anything on Google) and then ask on SO when you start having issue (and post the code you have tried to) - people will then be more willing to help

Comment: @ManInMoon If you have access to Matlab, there are a handful of implementations that use that (you could call it from your .NET code).  [Stats.SE] is the best place to go for the theory, but I think R is the weapon of choice over there.

Comment: jonsca - I would like it in c#. I know there are matlab and R libraries - but I want c# source. Someone has definiftely written this and I am just waiting for them to read my request!